# Password hashing using Python produces odd results on Solaris 10 & 11

Tags: python, solaris

Using an answer from [a serverfault submission](https://serverfault.com/questions/330069/how-to-create-an-sha-512-hashed-password-for-shadow) I generated password hashes for `/etc/shadow`, however the result on Windows (Cygwin) or Mac:

```
mistral.local:~(16)+>- python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("test","$6$randomsalt")'
$6asQOJRqB1i2
mistral.local:~(17)+>-
```

is very different to that on Solaris 10 & 11:

```
pkearns@solaris11:~/tmp$ python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("test","$6$randomsalt")'
$6$randomsalt$gZCCiaoqM7ivJDVPx3T4hr23J7WDQjneAucycYvJeMoBZHAx9bx8y2pUL.hE2MhbSRcgTjEE9klIhBq1WF8Pa1
pkearns@solaris11:~/tmp$
```

Can anyone explain that?

Comment: Possibly a difference in endianness?

Comment: @TomO'Connor The two examples shown are on the same processor (Mac, and Solaris on VirtualBox on the same Mac).  The Solaris result is the same on SPARC and Intel.

Answer (score 1):

Crypt is a function to make hash consistent with system.

I'm not sure about Mac and Windows, but on a linux system it's a modified DES, for Solaris it's plugable algorithms, with SHA-256 or SHA-512 recommended to use.

If you need to make a password hash for you software - you'd better use hashlib.

Comment: You mean like this (to borrow from another submission): `python -c "import hashlib; m = hashlib.sha512(); m.update('Ii4CGbr7'+'usrpw123'); print m.hexdigest()"`

Answer (score 0):

[crypt module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html) is only available in Unix.

Maybe you're using your own version of crypt in your system.

Try following command to tell where the crypt module come from:

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.__file__'
```

Comment: I should have said the Windows one was Cygwin (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/crypt.dll); I have amended my submission accordingly.  That `__file__` is handy though.